# How to insert table notes between caption and table

Tags: tables

How can I incorporate table notes like in this example?
[image]

Right now, I have the following Tex:

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
 \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
 \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
 \usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=3.3cm, right=3.3cm]{geometry}


 \begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]                                            
 \small 
 \centering         
 \caption{Granger Causality}                                                    

 \label{table:grangercausality}                                             
 \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}      
 \begin{tabular}{l *{11}{d{3.3}}}                       
 \toprule                                           
 \hspace{1mm}1  &       2       &       3       &       4       &       5       
 &      6       &       7       &       8       &       9       &       10      
 &      11      &       12      \\  
 \hspace{2.5mm}i    &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,AUS}$}      &       
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,CAN}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,FRA}$}      &   
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,DEU}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,ITA}$}      &   
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,JPN}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,NLD}$}      &   
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,SWE}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,CHE}$}      &   
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,GBR}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,USA}$}      \\  
 \midrule
 AUS    &               &       0.11^\ast       &       0.12^\ast       &       
 0.13^\ast      &       0.08^\ast       &       0.10^\ast       &       
 0.13^\ast      &       0.08^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       &       0.07        
 &      0.20^\ast       \\
    &   &   (1.35)  &   (1.96)  &   (2.06)  &   (2.24)  &   (1.91)  &   
 (1.77) &   (1.91)  &   (1.67)  &   (0.94)  &   (2.34)  \\  \addlinespace
 CAN    &       0.05        &               &       0.06        &       0.06        
 &      0.06^\ast       &       0.06        &       0.06        &       
 0.15^\ast      &       0.08        &       0.07        &       0.21^\ast       
 \\ 
    &   (0.84)  &   &   (1.21)  &   (1.24)  &   (1.53)  &   (1.26)  &   
 (0.79) &   (3.73)  &   (1.00)  &   (0.99)  &   (2.19)  \\  \addlinespace
 FRA    &       0.01        &       -0.01       &               &       
 -0.03      &       -0.05       &       0.04        &       0.002       &       
 0.14^\ast      &       0.16^\ast       &       0.03        &       0.12        
 \\
    &   (0.15)  &   (-0.15) &   &   (-0.31) &   (-0.91) &   (0.53)  &   
 (0.02) &   (2.27)  &   (1.47)  &   (0.26)  &   (1.28)  \\  \addlinespace
 DEU    &       0.03        &       0.09        &       0.13^\ast       &               
 &      0.06        &       0.09^\ast       &       0.06        &       
 0.14^\ast      &       0.26^\ast       &       0.07        &       
 0.22^\ast      \\  
    &   (0.37)  &   (1.11)  &   (1.49)  &   &   (1.29)  &   (1.42)  &   
 (0.55) &   (2.49)  &   (2.26)  &   (0.77)  &   (2.33)  \\  \addlinespace
 ITA    &       -0.01       &       0.06        &       0.16^\ast       &       
 0.11       &               &       0.05        &       -0.06       &       
 0.06       &       0.21^\ast       &       0.15^\ast       &       
 0.15^\ast      \\  
    &   (-0.07) &   (0.66)  &   (1.63)  &   (1.21)  &       &   (0.72)  &   
 (-0.59)    &   (0.99)  &   (1.84)  &   (1.48)  &   (1.59)  \\  
 \addlinespace
 JPN    &       0.04        &       0.12^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       
 &      0.02        &       0.03        &               &       0.07        
 &      0.09^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       &       
 0.11^\ast      \\  
    &   (0.70)  &   (1.70)  &   (2.07)  &   (0.44)  &   (0.78)  &   &   
 (1.17) &   (1.77)  &   (1.61)  &   (1.71)  &   (1.48)  \\  \addlinespace
 NLD    &       0.10^\ast       &       0.15^\ast       &       0.15^\ast       
 &      0.15^\ast       &       0.05        &       0.11^\ast       &               
 &      0.16^\ast       &       0.33^\ast       &       0.11        &       
 0.32^\ast      \\  
    &   (1.46)  &   (1.95)  &   (2.20)  &   (1.79)  &   (1.05)  &   (2.12)  
 &      &   (2.76)  &   (3.28)  &   (1.11)  &   (3.69)  \\  \addlinespace
 SWE    &       -0.03       &       0.16^\ast       &       0.05        &       
 0.08       &       0.08        &       0.06        &       0.01        &               
 &      0.12        &       0.10        &       0.23^\ast       \\  
    &   (-0.31) &   (1.75)  &   (0.58)  &   (0.88)  &   (1.09)  &   (0.76)  
 &  (0.13)  &   &   (1.23)  &   (0.90)  &   (2.22)  \\  \addlinespace
 CHE    &       0.03        &       0.03        &       -0.0003     &       
 -0.02      &       0.00        &       0.02        &       -0.01       &       
 0.13^\ast      &               &       0.02        &       0.14^\ast       
 \\ 
    &   (0.50)  &   (0.41)  &   (0.07)  &   (-0.20) &   (-0.08) &   (0.51)  
 &  (-0.08) &   (3.14)  &       &   (0.32)  &   (1.67)  \\\addlinespace 
 GBR    &       0.11^\ast       &       0.08        &       0.08        &       
 0.02       &       0.01        &       0.09^\ast       &       -0.02       
 &      0.09^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       &               &       
 0.23^\ast      \\  
    &   (1.74)  &   (1.02)  &   (1.17)  &   (0.26)  &   (0.24)  &   (1.85)  
 &  (-0.18) &   (2.03)  &   (1.42)  &       &   (2.26)  \\\addlinespace 
 USA    &       0.06        &       0.03        &       0.01        &       
 -0.01      &       0.06^\ast       &       -0.0003     &       0.01        
 &      0.09^\ast       &       0.04        &       0.02        &               
 \\ 
    &   (1.00)  &   (0.27)  &   (0.20)  &   (-0.20) &   (1.52)  &   (-0.01) 
 &  (0.18)  &   (2.31)  &   (0.48)  &   (0.22)  &       \\  \addlinespace
 Average    &       0.04        &       0.08        &       0.09        &       
 0.05       &       0.04        &       0.06        &       0.03        &       
 0.11       &       0.15        &       0.08        &       0.19        \\  
 \addlinespace
 Pooled &       0.03        &       0.07^\ast       &       0.08^\ast       
 &      0.05        &       0.04^\ast       &       0.06^\ast       &       
 0.02       &       0.11^\ast       &       0.13^\ast       &       
 0.08^\ast      &       0.17^\ast       \\  
    &   (0.65)  &   (1.34)  &   (2.02)  &   (1.08)  &   (1.32)  &   (1.52)  
 &  (0.42)  &   (3.56)  &   (2.22)  &   (1.45)      &   (2.98)  \\      
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}    
 \end{document}
```

Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: please extend your code sniped to complete but small document. you use some commands in table which aren't defined ... help us to help you!

Comment: Hi! I used the following packages for the table:
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} 
\usepackage{float}

Comment: So before the table:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}

and after:
\end{document}

Comment: In order to get it in the center, just use this extra command:
\usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=3.3cm, right=3.3cm]{geometry}

Comment: please eddit your question and add this code to your code sneppet!. As dirty trick you can define `\multicolumn{12}{>{\footnotesize}p{\linewidth}{... <noe>...}` .

Comment: Sorry man! I am new to this haha, did not know I could edit the question and I did not have enough characters for putting it in the comments

Comment: I can not fix the problem with your comment, I don't know where to put it in the Tex

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Like this?

[image]

a I mentioned in comment above, you can use for note `\multicolumn{12}{>{\linespread{0.8}\footnotesize}p{\linewidth}}{...}`. With `\linespread{0.8}` in is reduced vertical space between text lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
 \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
 \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
 \usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=3.3cm, right=3.3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
 \small
 \centering
 \caption{Granger Causality}

 \label{table:grangercausality}
 \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
 \begin{tabular}{l *{11}{d{3.3}}}
 \multicolumn{12}{>{\linespread{0.8}\footnotesize}p{\linewidth}}{\lipsum[11]}\\
 \toprule
 \hspace{1mm}1  &       2       &       3       &       4       &       5
 &      6       &       7       &       8       &       9       &       10
 &      11      &       12      \\
 \hspace{2.5mm}i    &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,AUS}$}      &
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,CAN}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,FRA}$}      &
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,DEU}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,ITA}$}      &
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,JPN}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,NLD}$}      &
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,SWE}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,CHE}$}      &
 \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,GBR}$}     &       \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{i,USA}$}      \\
 \midrule
 AUS    &               &       0.11^\ast       &       0.12^\ast       &
 0.13^\ast      &       0.08^\ast       &       0.10^\ast       &
 0.13^\ast      &       0.08^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       &       0.07
 &      0.20^\ast       \\
    &   &   (1.35)  &   (1.96)  &   (2.06)  &   (2.24)  &   (1.91)  &
 (1.77) &   (1.91)  &   (1.67)  &   (0.94)  &   (2.34)  \\  \addlinespace
 CAN    &       0.05        &               &       0.06        &       0.06
 &      0.06^\ast       &       0.06        &       0.06        &
 0.15^\ast      &       0.08        &       0.07        &       0.21^\ast
 \\
    &   (0.84)  &   &   (1.21)  &   (1.24)  &   (1.53)  &   (1.26)  &
 (0.79) &   (3.73)  &   (1.00)  &   (0.99)  &   (2.19)  \\  \addlinespace
 FRA    &       0.01        &       -0.01       &               &
 -0.03      &       -0.05       &       0.04        &       0.002       &
 0.14^\ast      &       0.16^\ast       &       0.03        &       0.12
 \\
    &   (0.15)  &   (-0.15) &   &   (-0.31) &   (-0.91) &   (0.53)  &
 (0.02) &   (2.27)  &   (1.47)  &   (0.26)  &   (1.28)  \\  \addlinespace
 DEU    &       0.03        &       0.09        &       0.13^\ast       &
 &      0.06        &       0.09^\ast       &       0.06        &
 0.14^\ast      &       0.26^\ast       &       0.07        &
 0.22^\ast      \\
    &   (0.37)  &   (1.11)  &   (1.49)  &   &   (1.29)  &   (1.42)  &
 (0.55) &   (2.49)  &   (2.26)  &   (0.77)  &   (2.33)  \\  \addlinespace
 ITA    &       -0.01       &       0.06        &       0.16^\ast       &
 0.11       &               &       0.05        &       -0.06       &
 0.06       &       0.21^\ast       &       0.15^\ast       &
 0.15^\ast      \\
    &   (-0.07) &   (0.66)  &   (1.63)  &   (1.21)  &       &   (0.72)  &
 (-0.59)    &   (0.99)  &   (1.84)  &   (1.48)  &   (1.59)  \\
 \addlinespace
 JPN    &       0.04        &       0.12^\ast       &       0.11^\ast
 &      0.02        &       0.03        &               &       0.07
 &      0.09^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       &
 0.11^\ast      \\
    &   (0.70)  &   (1.70)  &   (2.07)  &   (0.44)  &   (0.78)  &   &
 (1.17) &   (1.77)  &   (1.61)  &   (1.71)  &   (1.48)  \\  \addlinespace
 NLD    &       0.10^\ast       &       0.15^\ast       &       0.15^\ast
 &      0.15^\ast       &       0.05        &       0.11^\ast       &
 &      0.16^\ast       &       0.33^\ast       &       0.11        &
 0.32^\ast      \\
    &   (1.46)  &   (1.95)  &   (2.20)  &   (1.79)  &   (1.05)  &   (2.12)
 &      &   (2.76)  &   (3.28)  &   (1.11)  &   (3.69)  \\  \addlinespace
 SWE    &       -0.03       &       0.16^\ast       &       0.05        &
 0.08       &       0.08        &       0.06        &       0.01        &
 &      0.12        &       0.10        &       0.23^\ast       \\
    &   (-0.31) &   (1.75)  &   (0.58)  &   (0.88)  &   (1.09)  &   (0.76)
 &  (0.13)  &   &   (1.23)  &   (0.90)  &   (2.22)  \\  \addlinespace
 CHE    &       0.03        &       0.03        &       -0.0003     &
 -0.02      &       0.00        &       0.02        &       -0.01       &
 0.13^\ast      &               &       0.02        &       0.14^\ast
 \\
    &   (0.50)  &   (0.41)  &   (0.07)  &   (-0.20) &   (-0.08) &   (0.51)
 &  (-0.08) &   (3.14)  &       &   (0.32)  &   (1.67)  \\\addlinespace
 GBR    &       0.11^\ast       &       0.08        &       0.08        &
 0.02       &       0.01        &       0.09^\ast       &       -0.02
 &      0.09^\ast       &       0.11^\ast       &               &
 0.23^\ast      \\
    &   (1.74)  &   (1.02)  &   (1.17)  &   (0.26)  &   (0.24)  &   (1.85)
 &  (-0.18) &   (2.03)  &   (1.42)  &       &   (2.26)  \\\addlinespace
 USA    &       0.06        &       0.03        &       0.01        &
 -0.01      &       0.06^\ast       &       -0.0003     &       0.01
 &      0.09^\ast       &       0.04        &       0.02        &
 \\
    &   (1.00)  &   (0.27)  &   (0.20)  &   (-0.20) &   (1.52)  &   (-0.01)
 &  (0.18)  &   (2.31)  &   (0.48)  &   (0.22)  &       \\  \addlinespace
 Average    &       0.04        &       0.08        &       0.09        &
 0.05       &       0.04        &       0.06        &       0.03        &
 0.11       &       0.15        &       0.08        &       0.19        \\
 \addlinespace
 Pooled &       0.03        &       0.07^\ast       &       0.08^\ast
 &      0.05        &       0.04^\ast       &       0.06^\ast       &
 0.02       &       0.11^\ast       &       0.13^\ast       &
 0.08^\ast      &       0.17^\ast       \\
    &   (0.65)  &   (1.34)  &   (2.02)  &   (1.08)  &   (1.32)  &   (1.52)
 &  (0.42)  &   (3.56)  &   (2.22)  &   (1.45)      &   (2.98)  \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Not very elegant, but it works ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! And again sorry for not editing the question directly!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the backslash! The text before and after my tables has a specific linespread. Is it possible to make the text in the \multicolumn{12}{>{footnotesize}p{\linewidth}}{\lipsum[11]}\\ without linespread so the notes are more compact?